# Find date difference of two document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection containing documents below:

```
{ type: 1,
  user: 1,
  date: "2019-01-01 11:52"
},
{ type: 1,
  user: 2,
  date: "2019-01-01 11:55"
},
{ type: 2,
  user: 2,
  date: "2019-01-01 12:02"
},
{ type: 2,
  user: 1,
  date: "2019-01-01 12:10"
},
```

and I want to to find time spent between types and for the same user. For Example:

```
{ user: 1,
  time: 18// minutes
},
{ user: 2,
  time: 7
}
```

How can this be possible with mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that there will only ever be two documents per user. My answer would be different if you wanted to calculate the time difference between more than two types per user. These are the steps I would take in achieving this:

- Get collection from MongoDB using the find() function.
- Create a new empty object to hold your results in.
- Loop over each document in the collection:
- If the user id does not exist in the results object, add the user to the results object along with its type and date.
- If the user id already exists in the results object, calculate the time difference between this document and the previously saved date in the results object.
- Remove the type and date from the results collection.

### Code (not tested)

```
/* Get the collection from MongoDB. */
collection_name.find({}, function (err, collection) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    } else {
        /* Create results object */
        var results = {};
        /* Loop over each document in the collection. */
        for(doc in collection){
            /* If the user doesn't exist in the results object. */
            if(typeof results[doc.user] == 'undefined'){
                /* Add the user to the results object. */
                results[doc.user] = {"type": doc.type, "date": doc.date};
            }
            /* If the user already exists in the results object. */
            else if(typeof results[doc.user] != 'undefined'){
                /* Calculate the time difference in milliseconds. */
                var diff = Math.abs(new Date(results[doc.user].date) - new Date(doc.date));
                /* Convert to minuets and save to results. */
                results[doc.user].time = Math.floor((diff/1000)/60);
                /* Remove date and type from results. */
                delete results[doc.user].date;
                delete results[doc.user].type;
            }
         }
         console.log(results);
     }
});
```

The resulting object should look something like this:

```
{
 1: {
  "time": 3 
 },
 2: {
  "time": 5
 },
 3: {
  "time": 2 
 },
 4: {
  "time": 4 
 }
}
```

The key in the results object is the user id. This program calculates the absolute time difference between two dates from two documents with different types per user in minutes. The code would be slightly more complex if you wanted to calculate the time difference between more than two types.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/)

Subtracts two numbers to return the difference, or two dates to return the difference in milliseconds, or a date and a number in milliseconds to return the resulting date.

```
{ $subtract: [ <expression1>, <expression2> ] }
```